# Implementation of command pattern for a game

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, graphics, game-engine, game-development

I am currently trying to improve in game architecture. After reading this article: [resource_command](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html) I rewrote some of my old input handling code.
My new classes are:

```
public abstract class Command{
public abstract void execute(GameObject g);
}

public class MoveLeftCommand extends Command{
public void execute(GameObject g){
   g.transform.position.x--;
    }
}
```

So you get the idea...

The author of the linked article later lets the handleInput method in InputHandler class (I just copied it) return the created command. He misses out how to recieve it after that.

In my implementation I just ask the InputHandler to handleInput() and store the given command.(I expanded it by returning a list of commands so multiple keystrokes at one time would not disappear).
I then loop through that list and call execute with the player's gameobject as parameter.

All that works fine if there is just "the game itself".
Suppose the keys "wasd" are represented with 4 classes extending "command" then every entity can be moved in all directions. But what if there is also a menu screen?
There "wasd" is used to move through gui elements like buttons. Unfortunatley pressing "wasd" would then just move the(not rendered) entity and the menu-panel couldn't be controlled...

Hopefully you could follow me up to this point and my question is how this pattern, as shown in the article, can be implemented when it has to switch between different "game-views" / panels?

I already searched the whole internet but couldn't find any ideas on how to do this!

Comment: You need different input modes. Your inputs have different effects in a different state of your application. In your example, when a menu is shown then WASD should not move some player but e.g. navigate through the menu's buttons. Let the InputHandler know which mode it is currently in, something like `theInputHandler.setCurrentState(State.MENU)` and let it return/execute different `Command`s based on the state.

Comment: @f1sh Thank you for the quick respone! I already thought about your approach but wouldn't it "destroy" best practice since I would end up with many different if/else to check for different game states?!

Comment: Because I believe that commands strength is to actually remove ugly code like: if(gamestate == menu)         if(gamestate == game) ...

Comment: Use the new [InputSystem (InputActions)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.5/manual/index.html)! It allows you to define different sets  of actions (= Action Maps)  - they can overlap and listen to same inputs - you can enable and disable the individual groups of actions which totally already covers for those game state differentiation

Comment: @derHugo I am implementing in Java and do not use Unity ;)...

Comment: Then what the is the `unity3d` tag for on your question? o.O And `GameObject` and the rest pretty much looks like Unity API though ...

Comment: I think that Unity user would most likely understand my question.

Comment: And I copied some "Unity-ideas"

Comment: Well Unity users would recommend you use the according Unity tools already doing exactly what your re asking for ;) If you don't have those (since you don't actually use Unity at all) you will have to implement that yourself which is basically what previous comments suggested .. have sets of InputActions (they are basically events triggered by a certain input) for the different app states and simply enable and disable those sets in the according states => you can simply attach listeners to the events without every time having to check for the app state in the listeners side

Comment: @derHugo You mean something like storing keyEvents and their corresponding gameaction in some sort of datastructure(as pairs). By doing this for different game states it would be possible to switch between them?

Comment: Yeah Unity's input goes a bit beyond and you can multiple different inputs (keys, different devices etc) bound to an action. Then each action has events like `started`, `ended` etc. !they also have pre/postprocessing and filters etc but let's skip those for now ;) ). And then each action belongs to an action map. Here multiple actions are bundled and can be en/disabled individually or via the entire map. You can use those maps to control which actions should be triggered in which app state and thereby how inputs are processed differently depending on the app state and active action map(s)

Comment: I think you could still watch some Unity tutorials about the `New Input System` (you will find plenty searching for that) in order to get a better understanding of what I mean and how you could implement your own specced down version of it